# How can I record the value of a bootstrap dropdown menu after submit is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

My form has one dropdown menu and 4 text input boxes. When the form is submitted, I need to console.log all the values. So far no problem with the text boxes but I can't record the number selected on the drop down menu. Can someone please help thanks in advance.

This is my html:

```
  <div class="container-of-forms">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          2
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul id="list" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-info" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Text Input Boxes -->
      <div class="container-inner">
        <input class="text-input-box" id="choice1" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 1"> <br>
        <input class="text-input-box" id="choice2" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 2"> <br>
        <input class="text-input-box invisible threeChoices" id="choice3" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 3"> <br>
        <input class="text-input-box invisible fourChoices" id="choice4" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Choice 4">
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var choice1 = $("#choice1").value;
  var choice2 = $("#choice2").value;
  var choice3 = $("#choice3").value;
  var choice4 = $("#choice4").value;
  var numberOfChoices = $("#dropdownMenu").value;
  console.log(numberOfChoices);}
```

But it is not printing the numberOfChoices...please help...thanks

Comment: That's not JavaScript. That's jQuery, and it's not even correct for that. JavaScript would be `document.getElementById('dropdownMenu').value;`

Comment: First of, you have no button SUBMIT. Second, don't listen to SUBMIT button clicks, rather attach an on `"submit"` event handler right on your FORM element. Third, that's jQuery, not pure JavaScript. therefore, if you use jQuery it's `$("#choice1").val()`, not `$("#choice1").value`

Comment: It looks like you're using some other js to use a `button` and a `ul` as a "dropdown menu". Can you share this js or at least describe the behavior? Just guessing from the markup, I'd assume when the user clicks one of the dropdown choices, the text value in the button is updated to the selected choice - is that correct?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I don't have a form element as its a game..do I need a form element? Also, '$("#choice1").val()' works but '$("#dropdownMenu").val()' doesnt work

Comment: @defines Yes..it's a bootstrap dropdown menu

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Sorry my bad, I added Jquery into the topics of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that we're attempting to access the `value` of a `button` which has no `value` attribute set.

We might suggest setting the `value`, but in this case as you're using a third-party control, let's just access the text inside the `button` instead:

```
var numberOfChoices = $("#dropdownMenu").text();
```

Note that `text()` will return all text of the selected node and all descendents, which in this case includes the caret `span` which has no inner text, thus returning just the selected "value" from the bootstrap dropdown.

Comment: Waaaait how did I not even notice that it was not a `<select>` like it should be?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol What do u mean? Is it better if I make it <select>?